# Simplifying expression involving the multinomial distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm interested in simplifying the expression

$$
\sum_{\substack{x_1+\ldots+x_N=M \\ x_1,\ldots,x_N\ge 1}} \frac{1}{N^M} \frac{M!}{x_1!...x_N!}, \quad M\ge N
$$

which corresponds to the probability that each component of a multinomially distributed random variable $(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ is at least $1$ ($\Leftrightarrow \text{not } 0$), so when thinking of urns, it is the probability that when drawing $M$ balls from an urn with $N$ different kinds of balls, replacing the ball after each draw, you drew each kind of ball at least once.

Comment: This is the same as the fraction of all functions from $\{1,\ldots,M\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ that are surjective. So by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the sum is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^{N-k}\binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^M.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you please explain, why that is?

Comment: Also from the definition of stirling numbers of the second kind ($S(n,k)$), we have that $N!S(M,N)=\sum_{\substack{x_1+\ldots + x_N=M\\x_1,\ldots ,x_N\geq 1}} \binom{M}{x_1,\ldots x_n}$. So it follows that your summation is equivalent to $\frac{N!}{N^M}S(M,N)$, which can lead to Sangchul's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $[N] = \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(X_1\geq 1,\ldots,X_N\geq 1)
&= \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{N} \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i \geq 1\}} \right]
= \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left( 1 - \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i = 0\}} \right)  \right] \\
&= \sum_{I \subset [N]} (-1)^{|I|} \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{i\in I} \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i = 0\}} \right],
\end{align*}

which is essentially the inclusion-exclusion principle. However, a moment of thought gives

$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{i\in I} \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i = 0\}} \right]
= \mathbf{P}(X_i = 0 \text{ for all } i \in I)
= \left(1 - \frac{|I|}{N}\right)^M.
$$

So the desired probability is equal to

$$
\sum_{I \subset [N]} (-1)^{|I|} \left(1 - \frac{|I|}{N}\right)^M
= \sum_{j=0}^{N} (-1)^{j} \binom{N}{j} \left(1 - \frac{j}{N}\right)^M, $$

which is the same as the formula in my comment via the substitution $k=N-j$.

Comment: Very nice proof, thanks. How does this relate to the fraction of surjective functions, though?

Comment: @mathemagician99, If $f$ is a function chosen uniformly at random from $[M]$ to $[N]$ and if we define $X_i = |f^{-1}(\{i\})|$ as the number of elements in $[M]$ that is mapped to $i$ by $f$, then $(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ has precisely the same multinomial distribution you are considering. This way, your expression counts the fraction of functions such that $f^{-1}(\{i\})$ is non-empty for each $i$, hence surjections.

Comment: That's impressive!